# Terraform - Error when Creating Lambda Versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to do an AWS-Terraform-GitHub pipeline for a serverless app. In terraform i define a lambda function and on push  i want to update the lambda function code and create a new lambda function version (to be used with an alias at a later date).

This is my code

```
data "archive_file" "zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambda/hello.js"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda/hello.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_terraform" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.zip.output_path
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.zip.output_path)

  function_name = var.project_name
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler       = "hello.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
  timeout       = 10
  publish       = true
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name               = "${var.project_name}-lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_assume_role_policy.json
}
```

When i do the initial push , or a a change that does not involve the code in lambda function everything works. However when i do a code modification i get this error on github workflow (on terraform apply)

```
│ Error: Error publishing Lambda Function (lambda-terraform-github-actions) version: ResourceConflictException: The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:961736190498:function:lambda-terraform-github-actions
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 409,
│     RequestID: "d8c86252-a471-46be-9662-751fc935083c"
│   },
│   Message_: "The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:961736190498:function:lambda-terraform-github-actions",
│   Type: "User"
│ }
│ 
│   with aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform,
│   on lambda.tf line 9, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_terraform":
│    9: resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_terraform" {
│ 
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform apply (exit 1)
```

I try adding depends_on but i still have the same problem .
I also try the same thing on a local environment , doing terraform apply on the same code without the pipeline but the same thing happens.

If i remove the "publish" the terraform apply works, the function gets updates but of course there is no new function version.

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.26.0"

Comment: Based on what you posted, there is no reason why changing `hello.js` would fail. Could be that you are using very outdated provider as Marko wrote.

Comment: Uff - did not spot that - everything worked fine once i updated to 4.34.0

Comment: For anyone else reading, this could be the source of the issue: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/coming-soon-expansion-of-aws-lambda-states-to-all-functions/. Older provider versions probably did not take the change into account.